# Understanding and using Unity's Physics2D.OverlapArea()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to write a script that instantiates a square prefab at a random location on screen. If the space is already occupied by a previously instantiated square, it should just write something in the console. Here's the code I've written:

```
    public void SpawnSquares(int difficulty){
    float R1=Random.Range(25.0f,_screenWidth);
    float R2=Random.Range(25.0f,_screenHeight);

    _overlapA=new Vector2(R1-50f,R2+50f);
    _overlapB=new Vector2(R1+50f,R2-50f);

    if(Physics2D.OverlapArea(_overlapA,_overlapB,layermask,Mathf.Infinity,Mathf.Infinity)==null){
        _position=Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(R1,R2,10));
        Instantiate(Resources.Load("Square",typeof (GameObject)),_position,Quaternion.identity);

    }
    else{
        Debug.Log("avoided collision");
    }
}
```

The layermask variable is set as layermask=1<<9; because all the squares are located on layer 9.

What I expected this to do was generate a random location and modify _overlapA and _overlapB to account for the size of the squares, then check if there are any colliders in that certain area. If there are not (OverlapArea()==null) then it should spawn a new square at that position. If the space is occupied just write to console.

What is actually happening? The execution never branches off on else, so that means Physics2D.OverlapArea(_overlapA,_overlapB,layermask,Mathf.Infinity,Mathf.Infinity) always returns null. However, after calling SpawnSquares() around 10 times the screen is pretty much filled up with squares so it should at least detect one collider.

What am I doing wrong? My project has stalled for the last two days because I can't seem to solve this issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You have a Logic Error, but you're clearly on the right path. Just missing the main Concept of checking.

3 Main problems.

1. You're checking your pre-Instantiated Physics2d so no matter what happens, it will return Null;

   ```
   if(Physics2D.OverlapArea(_overlapA,_overlapB,layermask,Mathf.Infinity,Mathf.Infinity)==null){
   _position=Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(R1,R2,10));
   Instantiate(Resources.Load("Square",typeof (GameObject)),_position,Quaternion.identity);

   }
   else{
       Debug.Log("avoided collision");
   }
   ```

The Logic here says, Hey check my Physics2d. If I am overlapping with "MyOwn _overlapA and _overlapB. Well it is Instantiated, this will always return true. But it is not yet instantiated, meaning it will always give you false.

To fix the problem, you will need to tell it to compare with "OTHER Physics2d" that exists in your game.

Example

```
if(Physics2D.OverlapArea(otherphysics2d.overlapA,otherphysics2d.overlapB
```

2. Now understanding the first solution, will make you think about the second problem. Which is how can I reference those I have instantiated? How can I get their Physics2D?

This is the part that you need to make a list

```
   // Needs to be out of the Method to be accessible to all.
     public List<GameObject> mySpawns = new List<GameObject>();
```

Now after you Instantiated them, add them to the list like this.

```
if(Physics2D.OverlapArea(_overlapA,_overlapB,layermask,Mathf.Infinity,Mathf.Infinity)==null){
    _position=Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(R1,R2,10));
GameObject newGameObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Square",typeof (GameObject)),_position,Quaternion.identity);
    mySpawns.Add(newGameObject);
    }
    else{
        Debug.Log("avoided collision");
    }

   // Take note that if you miss a cast for some reason, just add "as GameObject" at the end to DownCast it.
```

3. Checking part is How do you check every list. Easy use foreach.

   ```
    foreach(GameObject check in mySpawns)
        {
           vector2 MyX = check.Collider2D.transform.x;
           vector2 MyY = check.Collider2D.transform.y;                       if(Physics2D.OverlapArea(MyX,MyY,layermask,Mathf.Infinity,Mathf.Infinity)==null){
   _position=Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(R1,R2,10));
         GameObject newGameObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Square",typeof (GameObject)),_position,Quaternion.identity);
   mySpawns.Add(newGameObject);
   }
     else   {
          Debug.Log("avoided collision");
      }

   }
   ```
4. Lastly is what you can do on your Own. Just add a Physics2D component on your prefab and makesure there are in there and make sure there is no Physics on it cause it is for 3D.

Welcome to StockOverflow

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. And as much as I'm happy for finally having an answer, yours seems a bit...wrong. For example, unity documentation clearly states "Check if a collider falls within a rectangular area." which, in my opinion, means that I declare an area and the engine will see if there's any collider inside it. Also, that foreach loop will never execute, since the mySpawns List is always empty. And also, there's no Vector2 that can be declared like that as far as I know. Not to mention that the correct syntax would be `check.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().transform.position.x`

Comment: Just for the record, I tried your solution with a few tweaks and it doesn't work. Checking fails to detect anything.

Comment: I will try to do this in an empty project. Then.

Answer (score 0):

I know this a 7 year old post, but since the other answer is wrong I thought I'd answer it anyway.

The only thing wrong with your OverlapArea() call, is that you are checking for colliders with a minimum and a maximum depth of infinity. Since there are no values between infinity and infinity, no colliders will return. The only change that needs to be made is changing your minimum to `Mathf.NegativeInfinity`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).